# Where should I call an initializer function of a protected type in VHDL?

Tags: initialization, vhdl, simulation

I have a protected type in VHDL, which implements a initializer function or procedure.

Here is my code with an initializer procedure:

```
type T_SIM_STATUS is protected
  procedure init;
  procedure fail(Message : in STRING := "") ;
  procedure simAssert(condition : BOOLEAN; Message : STRING := "") ;
  procedure simReport;
end protected;

type T_SIM_STATUS is protected body
  variable NotImplemented : BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  variable Passed : BOOLEAN := TRUE;

  procedure init is
  begin
    NotImplemented := FALSE;
  end procedure;

  procedure fail(Message : in STRING := "") is
  begin
    if (Message'length > 0) then
      report Message severity error;
    end if;
    Passed := FALSE;
  end procedure;

  procedure simAssert(condition : BOOLEAN; Message : STRING := "") is
  begin
    if (condition = FALSE) then
      fail(Message);
    end if;
  end procedure;

  procedure simReport is
    variable l : LINE;
  begin
    write(l, STRING'("SIMULATION RESULT = "));
    if (NotImplemented = TRUE) then
      write(l, STRING'("NOT IMPLEMENTED"));
    elsif (Passed = TRUE) then
      write(l, STRING'("PASSED"));
    else
      write(l, STRING'("FAILED"));
    end if;
  end procedure;
end protected body;

shared variable simStatus : T_SIM_STATUS;
```

**Where should I call the `init` procedure?**

My current solution calls `init` in a seperate process in the testbench's architecture body:

```
architecture rtl of test is
  -- ...
begin
  procInit : process
  begin
    simStatus.init;
    wait;
  end process;

  procGenerator : process
  begin
    -- generate stimuli
    wait;
  end process;

  procTester : process
  begin
    -- check results by using simStatus.simAssert

   simStatus.simReport;
   wait;
  end process;
 end architecture;
```

**Are there better solutions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, and assuming effect of `init` should be made before any use of other procedures (methods) in the protected type, it looks like `init` procedure could be removed if `NotImplemented` if given an initial value of `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`.

Otherwise, if `init` is to be called first, just make sure that other uses of the shared variable are not called at time 0, in which case the call to `init` can be made as concurrent, thus without the `process` wrapper, but simply like:

```
simStatus.init;
```

If more complex setup must be done through a `init` call, then it could be called automatically when instantiating the shared variable if `init` is made as a function, that is then called from within the body of the shared variable, like:

```
type T_SIM_STATUS is protected
  -- No init function is made public
  procedure fail(Message : in STRING := "") ;
  procedure simAssert(condition : BOOLEAN; Message : STRING := "") ;
  procedure simReport;
end protected;

type T_SIM_STATUS is protected body
  variable NotImplemented : BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  variable Passed : BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  ...  # Other code
  impure function init return boolean is
  begin
    NotImplemented := FALSE;
    ...  -- Or other more complex code
    return TRUE;
  end function;
  variable dummy : boolean := init;  -- Calling init with side effects
end protected body;
```